# Cuando coloco > en html se desordena mi código

Tags: html, visual-studio

Estoy comenzando a usar Linux. Tal vez cambie algo por error, soy nuevo en programación. De un momento a otro me comenzó a pasar esto:

[image]

Cuando quiero colocar el > pasa lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pasa con todas las etiquetas. Todas bajan una línea y como resultado el código se desordena.

Comment: Que estas usando para crear tu html ?

Comment: Es normal, el programa que usar auto cierra la etiqueta, no veo motivo para que eso desborde tu código

Comment: Lo que comenta Elboy es correcto, esto no es un problema de la IDE o programa que usas, es solo un comportamiento normal.

Comment: Si estas usando visual studio en comportamiento normal dentro de cualquier IDE y para que queden bien Identadas las lineas puedes usar el comando ctrl+K , D. 
Por otro lado no tiene nada que ver linux en este tema. Es HTML y tu IDE la pregunta.